# Error coming while compiling contract in hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am trying to compile the following code
[My smart contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoZ9y.png)

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
 
 
contract GToken is ERC20, Ownable {
     
    constructor() ERC20("GToken", "GT") public {
    _mint(msg.sender, 50 * (10**18));
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REqHy.png)

```
contracts/GToken.sol:10:19: TypeError: Wrong argument count for modifier invocation: 2 arguments given but expected 0.
    constructor() ERC20("GToken", "GT") public {
                  ^-------------------^

Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";
```

This one is outdated and also change solidity version to >0.8.0

**Final Code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 
 
contract GToken is ERC20, Ownable {
     
    constructor() ERC20("GToken", "GT") public {
    _mint(msg.sender, 50 * (10**18));
}
}
```

Comment: but open zepplin uses 0.5.0 as solidity version

Comment: I am now getting following error:

Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

  * contracts/GToken.sol (0.8.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Problem has been resolved. I made following changes in contract.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 
 
contract GToken is ERC20, Ownable {
     
    constructor() ERC20() public {
    _mint(msg.sender, 50 * (10**18));
}
```

}